# on('connection') in Socket.IO gets triggered all the time. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Hi I've been using `socket.io` 4 years ago last time in my open-source node.js project and now when I updated everything to the new node and socket.io versions and when i call `io.on('connection')` from my `app.js` it seems to get triggered all the time even if there's no new connection to the server.

why is that? how i can fix that?

here's the code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user socket connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        console.log('user disconnected');
        <!-- ... -->
    }
    <!-- ... -->
```

});

So that message `a user socket connected` gets emitted even when i'm just looking at the page (not loading it). Is there some new way of doing things there which I don't know about?

Before it just emitted `a user socket connected` once and waited until the page is reloaded, which is the behavior I want.

Just in case the full source code (and of the `app.js` file) is available on http://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus

Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your client version of socket.io is exactly the same as your server version?  When they are mismatched, this is what can happen as the client keeps trying to connect over and over again.  For others, I've seen people using a specific socket.io version from a CDN that does not matched the newly upgraded server version.  If you fetch the client script with `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`, then you are guaranteed a match.

Comment: Also, if you just recently update the socket.io.js file that you server without changing its name, you may be subject to browser caching issues (where it caches the old version because it doesn't know there is a newer version).

Comment: @jfriend00 perhaps you want to post it as an answer as this solved my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that your client version of socket.io is exactly the same as your server version? When they are mismatched, this is what can happen as the client keeps trying to connect over and over again. For others, I've seen people using a specific socket.io version from a CDN that does not matched the newly upgraded server version. If you fetch the client script with

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

then you are guaranteed a match.  Also, if you just recently updated the `socket.io.js` file that you server is serving to the client without changing its name, you may be subject to browser caching issues (where it caches the old version because it doesn't know there is a newer version).